# How to callback the value given to one function to be used in a different function

Tags: c, function, callback

hey i am using c code and have written two functions. i need to pass the value given to one function into an equation that is contained in another function.

this is the first function that is given a value from user input:

```
double getAltitude()
{
double a;


printf("\nEnter altitude (m):");
scanf("%lf", &a);


if (a > 9000)
{
printf("Invalid input! Altitude must be between 0 and 9000m");
return getAltitude();
}
else if ( a < 0 )
{
printf("Invalid input! Altitude must be between 0 and 9000m");
return getAltitude();
}
return a; 
}
```

and i need to use this value entered by the user to solve an equation inside of this function

```
double density()
{
double density, a ;
density = (1.2 - 1.33*pow(10, -4)*a);
return density; 
}
```

where the user input from the first function should be called in place of the variable (a) in the density equation.

any help would be appreciated

cheers

Comment: Look up function arguements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the variable `double a` into the function density and call the density function before the getAltitude function ends. Also, as noted in the comments please tag the question correctly.

```
double getAltitude()
{
    double a;
    double x;

    printf("\nEnter altitude (m):");
    scanf("%lf", &a);


    if (a > 9000)
    {
        printf("Invalid input! Altitude must be between 0 and 9000m");
        return getAltitude();
    }
    else if ( a < 0 )
    {
        printf("Invalid input! Altitude must be between 0 and 9000m");
        return getAltitude();
    }
    x = density(a);
    return a; 
}


double density(double a){
     double density ;
     density = (1.2 - 1.33*pow(10, -4)*a);
     return density; 
}
```